# How to override wishlist template file view.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9

I have tried this two code in my local.xml file to override wishlist view.phtml

**First one:**

```
<wishlist_index_index translate="label">
        <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
                <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist" name="customer.wishlist" template="inquiry/wishlist/view.phtml"/>

        </reference>
    </wishlist_index_index>
```

But it is not showing the content of view.phtml though file got overridden by these two code.
**(OR)**

```
<wishlist_index_index translate="label">
            <reference name="customer.wishlist">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <template>inquiry/wishlist/view.phtml</template>
                </action>
        </reference>
    </wishlist_index_index>
```

Both are override my view.phtml file but content of view.phtml not showing.

what is the proper way to override wishlist view.phtml ?

Comment: Can you post your view.phtml file?

Comment: Also, if you share a screenshot of your directory structure, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things that could potentially be going wrong. First, I suggest checking to make sure that your local.xml file is being loaded. The easiest way to do this is by looking in other places you've made modifications to see if they work as well. Also, ensure that you're clearing the cache.

If nothing else works, I suggest overriding the template by creating a wishlist directory in your theme and adding in the view.phtml file, which you are trying to override. The fallback mechanism will use it instead of the original file.

Also, if you can post your view.phtml file, we can look it over to ensure it's error-free.